# How do I add a parameter to a URL path as a variable from local storage?

Tags: html, parameters, local-storage, href

Just as the question implies, I'm trying to get a local storage variable and use that as the parameter for an href link. I can not put in the parameter manually because there are many different values that it could be, so how do I attach this variable to the url path string?

Down below is the code for the href, I know that I cant just put the localStorage.getItem in the url, but this is just to get an idea of what I'm trying to do

```
<a
  href="subject-page.html?subjectID=localStorage.getItem('myFutureCurrenSubjectID')" 
  id="subject"
>
   Subject Name
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that takes care of that for you like this. Make sure the file is added or enclose within a script tag.

```html
<script>
  document.body.onload = function() {
    const value = localStorage.getItem('myFutureCurrenSubjectID');
    const url = `subject-page.html?subjectID=${value}`;
    const a = document.querySelector('#link');   
    a.href = URL;
   }
</script>

<body>
 <a id="link">Link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So i just tried the code, I put the function in the script tag at the bottom of the page, and when I click the href link, it says this file can not be accessed. I don't think the function can be run inside the quote marks

Comment: It opens a page that says "your file can not be accessed, it may have been moved, edited or deleted". The url is as follows: C:/Capstone/Draft%203/pages/getUrl(). it just passes the getUrl() in the href string

Comment: Changed the code, now the only thing that happens when i click the link is a # is added to the current page url, and doesn't switch pages. Quick question, do u think const url should be double quote?

Comment: No. I just modified the answer. Please check again.